# How many reds are there?

Tags: visible-light

If we take a red to have the light frequency of 480–400 THz, how many monochromatic reds are there, from the point of view of physics?

I am just a curious layperson, and googling doesn't yield an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're asking how many distinguishable wavelengths fall into the range that a human world identify as red, which is different than how many shades of red a human can see. The barrier to distinguishing between two wavelengths is the Planck length: $1.616199(97)\times 10^{-35}$ meters. If the difference in wavelengths of two light sources were less than the Planck length, you could not tell the colors apart, even with an ideal detector. 
The red range is 620 to 750 nm, which is $130\times 10^{-9}$m. Divide the red range by the Planck length to get $8\times 10^{27} $ different distinguishable reds.

Answer (score 1):

Light comes in packets at any specific frequency, but the range of possible frequencies is continuous. This means there are an infinite number of possible frequencies of red. Each one is considered, at least in physics, to be its own monochromatic red. Practically, you could establish some uncertainty in the frequency that allows you to separate the range into a finite number of packets, but technically, there *are* infinite possible frequencies in that range.

The packets you are thinking of would represent the brightness of the red light. Frequency is continuous